# Wrong accelerator underline on controls on high DPI

Tags: windows, firemonkey, delphi

I am having a problem, that accelerator key underlines on all controls do not get correctly rendered (too far down from the text) in a Firemonkey Application on Windows systems with higher DPI settings.I have attached a screenshot to demonstrate the problem.
Does anyone know how to fix this?
I am using Delphi 10.2 with Update 1.

[image: Wrong rendering]

Comment: Submit a bug report to the developer

Answer (score -1):

Found a fix myself.

In FMX.Objects.pas replace (line 4472)

```
LBaseline := TFontGlyphManager.Current.GetBaseline(ALayout.Font, ACanvas.Scale);
```

with

```
 LBaseline := TFontGlyphManager.Current.GetBaseline(ALayout.Font, 1);
```

and (lines 4483, 4484)

```
FUnderlineBeginPoint.Y := Ceil(FUnderlineBeginPoint.Y) + 1.5;
FUnderlineEndPoint.Y := Ceil(FUnderlineEndPoint.Y) + 1.5;
```

with

```
FUnderlineBeginPoint.Y := Ceil(FUnderlineBeginPoint.Y) + 1.5 * ACanvas.Scale; 
FUnderlineEndPoint.Y := Ceil(FUnderlineEndPoint.Y) + 1.5 * ACanvas.Scale;
```